# Why doesn't Eff have an arrow for the last return value

Tags: purescript

The excellent [PureScript book](https://leanpub.com/purescript/read#leanpub-auto-the-eff-monad) explains that

```
fullName :: forall r. Record (firstName :: String, lastName :: String | r) -> String
fullName person = person.firstName <> " " <> person.lastName
```

and then compares the `Eff` monad

```
import Prelude

import Control.Monad.Eff.Random (random)
import Control.Monad.Eff.Console (logShow)

main :: forall eff. Eff (console :: CONSOLE, random :: RANDOM | eff) Unit
main = do
  n <- random
  logShow n
```

My question is:
Why doesn't the signature of `main` contain a `->` before Unit i.e.

```
main :: forall eff. Eff (console :: CONSOLE, random :: RANDOM | eff) -> Unit
```

This would make it similar to the `-> String` as in the signature of `fullName`

An excerpt from the same chapter(emphasis mine):

> main is a computation with side-effects, which can be run in any
>   environment which supports random number generation and console IO,
>   and any other types of side effect, and which **returns** a value of type
>   Unit

.

Comment: Do you understand what it means that the kind of [`Eff`](https://pursuit.purescript.org/packages/purescript-eff/2.0.0/docs/Control.Monad.Eff#t:Eff) is `# ! -> * -> *`?

Comment: A bit. I have reread it and it does inform my understanding. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One difference between both functions is that `fullName` has a parameter (before the `->`). The function signature states that it takes some record and returns a string.

`main` does not take any parameters, because it is the "entry point" for an application, and it returns `Eff`. So `main` just returns *one* type. That type happens to have two *type parameters*.

Function parameters and type parameters look quite the same, but they are on different levels. Types that take parameters have a constructor and have their parameters applied to produce the actual type. It looks like function application, but on the type level! The "signature" of types is called *kind*... you can learn more about it, but think about it as "types of types".

Now `Eff` is a type that combines some effects and some "actual result". Its constructor is applied with an effect row as first parameter and the result type as second parameter. In the case of `main`, all it does is side-effects, so the "actual result" is `Unit`, which is basically nothing.

If the signature of `main` was:

```
main :: forall eff. Eff (console :: CONSOLE, random :: RANDOM | eff) -> Unit
```

that would imply that

- `Eff` only takes some effect row as type parameter (which does not match the definition of `Eff`)
- `main` takes that `Eff` as a parameter (but were would it come from?)
- `main` returns just `Unit`